# Conceptualising the effect of changes to the substitution parameter in a CES production function

Tags: production-function

I'm trying to have a conceptual understanding of what happens to the CES production function when the substitution parameter $\rho = \frac{\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon}$ changes, where $\epsilon$ is the elasticity of substitution.

Concretely, suppose that we have a CES production function in capital $K$ and labour $L$ with equal shares,
$$Y = F(K,L) = [K^\rho + L^\rho]^\frac{1}{\rho}.$$
Qualitatively, $\rho$ measures how strongly input factors $K$ and $L$ substitute or complement one another, where if $\rho < 0$ they are complements and if $\rho > 0$ they are substitutes. This all makes sense to me.

However, what I don't understand is the following: suppose I consider what happens to the output $Y$ when $\rho$ increases. In this case, plotting the graph suggests that $Y$ is non-decreasing with increases in $\rho$ (with an exception at $\rho = 0$). This is illustrated below in the graphs of $Y$ against $\rho$ for $\rho<0$ (left) and $\rho > 0$ (right) respectively.

[image: rho-negative]
[image: rho-positive]

This seems to suggest that if $K$ and $L$ are initially complements, say with $\rho = -5$, then if $\rho$ increases to $-1$ the total product decreases (or stays the same in some edge cases). While this can be shown mathematically, e.g. in [this other stackexchange post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52992/showing-that-the-ces-is-non-decreasing-in-the-elasticity-of-substitution), I'm pretty puzzled how this makes sense conceptually. Should I not expect that as $\rho$ increases from $-5$ to $-1$ then $K$ and $L$ would bottleneck each other *less*, and thus result in *more* output, i.e. greater $Y$?

I'm generally pretty confused about how I should think about this conceptually -- does this suggest that the CES is just unrealistic and doesn't capture such effects well? Is there perhaps something else behind this that I'm missing?